# How to get the total length of a two dimensional array? Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Suppose that I have a two dimensional array holding 8 teams (rows) and in each team there is 12-15 players. Is there a way to know the total amount of players exist in `String teams[][]` (WITHOUT looping)?

Comment: Yes. You can sums up the length of all teams

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441099/how-do-you-count-the-elements-of-an-array-in-java

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with streams:

```
long players = Arrays.stream(teams).flatMap(team -> Arrays.stream(team)).count();
```

Comment: ... which "loops" behind the scenes :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it manually. Use something like this:

```
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < teams.length;  i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < teams[i].length; j++)
            if(a[i][j] != null)
                count++;
    return count;
```

This assumes that fields in the array that do not contain a team member are simply `null`.